# Can I save blended animations as .anim?

Tags: animation, godot, asset-workflow

I've got two animations, and they blend well. Can I save the thing as a singular .anim file ?

[image: Animation blending graph screenshot]

Comment: Instead of filler, try including useful information like which version of Godot you're using.

Comment: @DMGregory godot takes 30 seconds to download and install, if one version let's me download .anim files created with AnimationTree node... I'm clearly going to use that specific version

Comment: Sadly, this is not a feature. However, it might be possible to create the equivalent `Animation` via code: You can iterate over the tracks, and the key frame, compute the key frames for the animation.

Comment: @Blue That's also good information to include. Some folks don't have the option to switch versions (project might be too far along, might be doing contract work that requires version X, etc) and so generally the people reading the questions aren't going to be making many of assumptions. The community only knows what you share & very terse questions lead to a lot of back & forth comments trying to hash out the necessary details. Sort of a it's trying to help you (share more info) to help us (because we'll better understand your situation) help you (by providing relevant answers).